# Are there any alternative to implement multiple html "submit" buttons in a form?

Tags: html, forms, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm writing this app to make easier write contracts:

http://contractpy.appspot.com/

But, instead of using the submit button to insert first and second contracting party data, I'd like to use one button to insert first contracting party data and another button to insert second contracting party data. I want this because sometimes there are two or more people as first contracting parties (or second contracting parties) and users should press "submit" button only after they have inserted all contracting parties to that contract. The best (or only) way to do this is using multiple submit buttons? There are any alternative?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I would split the form up into multiple forms so that there is no confusion between submit buttons to particular forms.

P.S. I was not able to take a look at your app due to restricted work access.